# SwiftUI: State management inside Lists

Tags: swiftui

Can someone, please, explain me why MyButton's label stays in **I'm pressed** state (should be clicked once) and never reverts to its initial state **Press Me** when I switch views in a list by clicking the yellow rectangle.

Here is the example:

```
import SwiftUI

struct MyButton: View {
    @State private var label: String
    
    init() {
        label = "Press Me"
    }
    
    var body: some View {
        Button() {
            label = "I'm Pressed"
        } label: {
            Text(label)
        }
    }
}

struct ContentView: View {
    enum Mode {
        case text
        case button
    }
    @State private var mode: Mode
    
    init() {
        mode = .button
    }
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            List{
                switch mode {
                case .button:
                    MyButton()
                case .text:
                    Text("No button here for sure!")
                }
            }
            Spacer()
            Button() {
                mode = mode == .text ? .button : .text
            } label: {
                Color(.yellow)
                    .frame(width: 100, height: 100)
                    
            }
        }
    }
}

struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ContentView()
    }
}
```

I understand that this behaviour is because MyButton is in the List. If the List is removed from the sources, then switching the views by tapping on the yellow rectangle does give me the result I expect, e.g. MyButton gets initial state **Press Me**. Why is it so different with the List then?

I'm aware I can "reset" state by providing different .id() to MyButton, but are there any other options? I also tried .onDisappear to reset the state, seems to work as well, but first of all I would really love to know why List is so special that it remembers state of a non-rendered MyButton?

Answer (score 0):

The `List` caches cell types. It is like `UITableView`'s `dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier`. And state inside view persist until anything changes, but in question code view is just removed and then inserted, ie. no data changed - it remains the same.

Comment: But the `.mode` data is changed, is not it enough? Which data exactly must be changed so that MyButton is recreated with a default state? Can I disable "cell types" caching?

Comment: MyButton is not changed. State is view's persistence. No. Use external view model or don't use state, or ... some injection on init, or ... actually that's already different question.